# Minimum number X such that X % P == N

Tags: algorithm

This question is taken from an ACM-ICPC Romanian archive.

> You are given T tuples of the form (N, P), find the smallest number X for every tuple such that X % P == N. If this is not possible, print -1. X can only be formed using digits from the set {2, 3, 5, 7}.

Example :

3

52 100

11 100

51 1123

Output for given example :

52

-1

322352

Restrictions :

1 ≤ P ≤ 5 * 10^6

1 ≤ N ≤ P - 1

I attempted solving this problem by using a recursive function that would build numbers with digits from the given set and check if the condition is met, but that is way too slow because I have no idea when to stop searching (i.e. when there's no solution for the given tuple).

The author hints at using BFS somehow, but I really don't see any way to construct a meaningful graph using the input data of this problem.

How would you approach solving this problem?

Comment: This is a site for asking programming questions.

Comment: I'm not looking for any form of argument, I've read my fair share of questions based on concepts similar to the ones used in my post. SO suggests 10 related questions that involve the same problem solving paradigm. This is a programming question.

Comment: @JamesKPolk - I would argue the question is appropriate, since OP is asking for computational help.

Comment: @user43389 - could you please provide the code that you've tried so far?

Comment: I honestly don't see the point in that other than unnecessarily making the post longer. I'm asking for ideas, not code.

Comment: Since it's modulo arithmetic you can make a simple loop and check if the value consists only of those allowed numbers. It will be very fast since you don't need to test every possible number, only some. In the last case less than 5000. I'll leave specifics to be figured out still.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen thank you for the idea, but I'm not quite sure how to set an upper limit on the loop, or how to decide if finding a solution is impossible for a given pair. Can you expand on that?

Comment: Sorry, I mistook the limit of P to be limit of X so the end position isn't as simple as I thought. Have to think a bit what it is...

Comment: You could also say: find the smallest non-negative integer N, so that `x = N * p + n` gives a valid x.

Comment: @maraca but at what point do you decide that X got too large or there's no solution? After all, that seems to be the biggest problem here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve this with a BFS, starting from 0, where adjacent vertices to a number n are 10n+2, 10n+3, 10n+5 and 10n+7. By keeping a record of all numbers mod p already queued, one can reduce the size of the search space, but more importantly know when the whole space has been searched.

Here's a simple Python implementation:

```py
import collections

def ns(n, p):
    q = collections.deque([0])
    done = set()
    while q:
        x = q.popleft()
        for d in [2, 3, 5, 7]:
            nn = 10 * x + d
            if nn % p in done:
                continue
            if nn % p == n:
                return nn
            q.append(nn)
            done.add(nn % p)
    return -1

assert ns(52, 100) == 52
assert ns(11, 100) == -1
assert ns(51, 1123) == 322352
assert ns(0, 55) == 55
```